# MS-Excel insert a image through macro

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I want to insert a image in MS - Excel 2007 with source of the image being
xyz.com/234.png

Now, I want to format the url of this image using some cell value.
Is it Possible.

Thanks,

Comment: not sure I see the programming related part?

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("http://xyz.com/234.png", 
   True, True, left, top, width, height)
```

but I'm not sure if it'll accept a URL in place of an image file name though.

[documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb209605%28office.12%29.aspx)